# How to implement the back-end interface to input message through the front-end in the socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to implement a full-duplex communication through java socket and can enter information through the front-end page.

After the two parties establish a connection through the socket, the front-end can call the url interface to enter the message to be sent, but now that I have implemented the `socket_send` method on the back-end through threads, I can only enter message in the console. If I want to implement the interface, the `socket_send` method requires the `ObjectOutputStream` type to call the `writeObject` method, but in the interface, I cannot get the `ObjectOutputStream`.

I want to know how can I enter the message I want to send in the `socket_send` thread through the front-end page?

```
class Server_send implements Runnable{
private final Socket socket;
Server_send(Socket socket){
    this.socket=socket;
}
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                System.out.print("Please input the msg to be sent:");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String str = sc.nextLine();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("type","chat");
                obj.put("msg",str);
                oos.writeObject(obj);
                oos.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need an `ObjectOutputStream` to send serialized JSON messages.

Comment: Could you please tell me specifically what method should be used？

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream` will try to use the default Java serialization mechanism, which you don't want anywhere except Java itself. The best library for JSON serialization is [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) if you need one.
Try to use this template:

```
  . . . 
  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  // Jackson's ObjectMapper is here
  bos.write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(msgObject));
  // also you can send plain strings
  bos.write("hello".getBytes());
  . . .
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Even if I use ```BufferedOutputStream```, I still need to get ```bos``` when calling the interface that sends message in the front end.